# Remove former employee User Profiles from SharePoint online Site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, user-accounts

i have one query. If User leaves organization means if we delete the user from Office 365 then ideally User profiles should be automatically get deleted from all the SharePoint online Site collections. but this is not happening in my case. i tried to look in to this case on google found following link about how to delete the former employee from "ALL Users List" of Sharepoint online.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3026385/how-to-remove-users-from-sharepoint-online

but i dont want manual intervention of SharePoint team to delete the users from SharePoint Sites. can We try to automate this process as soon as user gets deleted from Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

**if we delete the user from Office 365 then ideally User profiles should be automatically get deleted**

This is not a 100% correct, the user may be deleted by mistake! so it's not deleted immediately as you expect.

There is a `deletion proces`s which has a `retention period` (14 days) that depend on a `Cleanup Timer Job` and there are no settings to change this period.

So if you want to delete the user **immediately** you should delete it **manually** from `User Info List` as mentioned at your attached link.

Comment: Ok.. but even after 14 days of retention period, there are multiple user profiles in my Sharepoint online Site collections which are not deleted. but those users are deleted from Office 365 admin center.

Comment: Open SR with Microsoft, in my case, it's worked as I mentioned!!